# Find the command the application has spawned

Tags: linux, process, system-calls

Is there a way to find the command by which an application has launched an external process?

Motivation: I'm using an IDE Qt Creators which at some point calls a SFTP to transfer a file to a remote location. Presuming that the SFTP is spawned as a separate process by the IDE is there a way to find out what exact command did the IDE run?

Comment: While the command is running, or after the fact? Or do you want to see it as it happens?

Comment: @Gilles The time isn't important, just getting the actually run command and its parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strace -p <PID> -f` to trace child process that are created as a result of the `fork(2)`, `vfork(2)` and `clone(2)` system calls.

**Hint**: Using `-p PID -f` will attach all threads of the given PID if it is multi-threaded.